# For Loop, specific condition doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, loops

can anyone tell me why this loop produces an almost infinite negative numbers  despite I specified that it shouldn't exceed -10?

```
for (var person = 2; -10 < person < 10; person --) {
    console.log(person);
}
```

I expected it will count from 2 to -10

Comment: In short: you can't chain `<` in JS, the condition should be written in 2 parts with an "and":  `-10 < person && person < 10`. (`&&` is the "logical and", because there is a "bitwise and" too, `&`).

Comment: that's very elaborative, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Change your current code to this-

```
for (var person = 2; person >= -10; person --) {
  console.log(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a number is between two other, you should go like this

```js
for (var person = 2; -10 < person && person < 10; person --) {
    console.log(person);
}
```

when you chain `-10<person<10`, it gets interpreted as `((-10<person)<10)`, and first one is true till it becomes lesser than -10 or equals to it, so first the first part till it person becomes -10 it is like `(true<10)` and true is 1.so it returns true.
for the second part when person becomes lesser or equals to -10 `(-10<person)` returns false and false is 0 and it surely is lesser than 10 --> `(false<10)`, so it stays true forever and there goes infinite loop.